# Ssh and host name not reachable

Tags: ssh, hadoop2, vmware-workstation

While try configure a hadoop cluster  in vm workstation,i got struck in ssh configuration ,ping hostname gives hostname not reachable error,instead hostname if tried with IPaddress its pinging,can anyone help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a linux environment, you should update the /etc/hosts file correctly.

127.0.0.1   hostname

Comment: Actually its centos6.x environment,i configured 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain,list of hostnames of the cluster also per line...in /etc/hosts

Comment: You should update the /etc/sysconfig/network file as well. `NETWORKING=yes`
`HOSTNAME=<nameyouwant>`

Comment: I updated that  file too as networking=yes,hostname=master@hcl.com is it fine,anything else i need too?pls tell

Comment: A restart of the machine probably would do. `hostname=master` would be sufficient without the domain and @ is not applicable.

Comment: I tried that too but not worked ,actually it worked when i tried nat network mode in virtual.machine but when i changed to bridged mode for cluster setup in Vm, again all ssh configuration of hosts collapsed and not working now ,do u any idea on this?